# Why are the chat FAQ in almost identical links different?

Tags: bug, chat, user-interface, hyperlinks

These two links are almost identical, yet the displays are noticeably different. Why is that?

## `https://chat.stackoverflow.com/faq`

[image]

## `https://chat.stackoverflow.com/faq#`

[image]

Comment: Ah, what is missing is the `#<target>` part of your URLs. The page does change behaviour and, above all, style, when you add a target. Reproduced by clicking on the link, then *reloading the page*. Direct linking should do it too, for example, to the [highlighted *formatting* FAQ entry](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/faq#formatting) (so `#formatting` at the end of the URL).

Comment: yes, I wonder why is the black version maintained? There is no side box, no hyperlink for each section, no expansion on all other sections

Comment: That's because the page is broken; I'm changing this to a bug report.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are seeing the *direct URL linking to section* rendering versus the normal *visiting the FAQ* look.

When you are linked to the formatting FAQ entry from another page, the `#formatting` hashtag is added, so the URL looks like

```
https://chat.stackoverflow.com/faq#formatting
```

which links to the [specific formatting section](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/faq#formatting). This renders differently; the section on formatting is put at the top of the page, and the rest of the page lists other information you might want to know about (e.g. the rest of the FAQ).

Without a hash however, you are just taken to the FAQ page, so now there are sections on the right to jump between the various parts.

That said, the page does appear broken when you are in the 'specific section linked' state; the *collapse* and *below* links should bring you back to the 'full FAQ' state, but the JavaScript code on the page is b0rken; when I open the JS console I see:

```
TypeError: e.curCSS is not a function
```

(on both Firefox and Chrome). This means that the code was written for an older jQuery version; the `$.curCSS` function was never part of the official API and has since been removed.

Comment: I can't remember how "b0rken" should be spelled :(

Comment: @Ooker: It is spelled `b0rken`, because it is broken.

Comment: If I understand correctly the issue is still there ([see also](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/381184/chat-faq-links-differ-from-the-content-of-the-main-faq-page)). Will the devs still see this question with an accepted answer? Or do they only filter for the bug tag?

Comment: @AndrasDeak pretty sure that accepted answers do not remove bug reports from the radar.

Comment: `b0rken` isn't a word.  It's `b0rked` or simply `borked` (in polite company).

Comment: @daveloyall: the [internet does not agree](https://www.google.com/search?&q=b0rken). There is even a [Wiktionary entry](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/borken).

Comment: @MartijnPieters, the [internet does not disagree](https://www.google.com/search?safe=active&q="b0rked"). (In fact, I see 25k hits vs 19k hits.)  Even [Wictionary agrees](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/borked). (One page was created in [2006](https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=borked&action=history) and the other in [2016](https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=borken&action=history).) Anyway, I was approximately there when the word was minted. ;)

Comment: @daveloyall: you do know that I use the term in jest, right? I'm really not all that interested in spelling corrections on that term, to be honest. *Both* terms are entirely made up, joke variations of "broken".

Comment: @MartijnPieters yes of course. :) me too!