# Chat FAQ links differ from the content of the main FAQ page

Tags: bug, chat, user-interface

Related to [this question about why they look different](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362554/why-are-the-chat-faq-in-almost-identical-links-different), but not the same issue. That question was dealing with the poor UX and the fact that if you load the page with a fragment it works incorrectly.

In SOCVR, our FAQ links to the chat formatting page with reference to "oneboxing". Today I discovered that page has no information on the subject. After some poking around, I discovered that the main page does indeed cover the subject

1. Open https://chat.stackoverflow.com/faq (note no fragment initially, this is important)
2. Scroll down to **How do I format my messages?**
3. Click **Show More**

And there it is
[image: Onebox description]

If we go to https://chat.stackoverflow.com/faq#formatting , however, that section is missing.

I'm not asking for a fix to the overall fragment problem, I'm simply asking that the linkable pages contain the same information as the main page, especially since loading one view locks you out of seeing the other.

Comment: All the details in the "show more" section of the main faq page are missing in the fragmented version.  Oneboxing happens to be in that section, but there's other examples in the other sections.  Seems simpler to just fix the linked issue?

Comment: [The `col-detail` css class has `display:none`](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/46868642#46868642).

Comment: [The Chat FAQ page uses a deprecated jQuery function](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/362555/).