# chat.stackoverflow.com/faq broken collapse/expand functionality

Tags: bug, chat

Just noticed a bug in https://chat.stackoverflow.com/faq <strike>and it doesn't seem to have been reported yet.</strike>

**Edit** (*with a little help from my friends)*: turns out it was reported a few other times:

- cross-site dupe: [TypeError in console on Chat FAQ page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309336/typeerror-in-console-on-chat-faq-page)
- exact dupe: [Why are the chat FAQ in almost identical links different?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362554/why-are-the-chat-faq-in-almost-identical-links-different)
- related: [Chat FAQ links differ from the content of the main FAQ page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/381184/chat-faq-links-differ-from-the-content-of-the-main-faq-page)

---

**Description**

Page loses its expand/collapse functionality (and some styling) when loaded through a link to one of the questions, e.g. https://chat.stackoverflow.com/faq#retention

Feel free to tag, modify or move this appropriately so it makes it on the *to-do-list* of whoever can fix it.

---

I'm seeing this on

- Chrome v83.0.4103.116 (Official Build) (64-bit)
- FF v77.0.1

---

**Error** shown: `Uncaught TypeError: e.curCSS is not a function` on `help.js:221:formatted`

Comment: Console error `Uncaught TypeError: e.curCSS is not a function`

Comment: cross site dupe: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309336/typeerror-in-console-on-chat-faq-page

Comment: Chat has been abandoned for a few years. This probably won't be fixed any time soon

Comment: Related/duplicate: [Chat FAQ links differ from the content of the main FAQ page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/381184/chat-faq-links-differ-from-the-content-of-the-main-faq-page).

Comment: @Makyen. not an exact dupe, but the one it relates to is: [Why are the chat FAQ in almost identical links different?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362554/why-are-the-chat-faq-in-almost-identical-links-different). Good find!

Comment: Previously reported on [meta.se], but with no response: [Collapse/show more does not work in chat faq when linked to a specific section](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/304225).